# Fluent ffmpeg how to user save callback

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-s3, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I am using fluent-ffmpeg
[GIT](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg)
I want to further process the saved file. But save do not have any callback. how can I use the saved file with promise. 
My code is

```
ffmpeg(filename)
    .toFormat('mp3')
    .on('error', (err) => {
       console.log('An error occurred: ' + err.message);
    })
    .on('progress', (progress) => {
        console.log('Processing: ' + progress.targetSize + ' KB converted');
})
.on('end', () => {
        console.log('Processing finished !');
})
.save(`./${newname}.mp3`)
```

My problem is "save" function do not have a callback. so how could I save the output on S3 again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`save` method does not need its own callback. As the documentation explains,

> save(filename): save the output to a file
>
> **Starts ffmpeg processing and saves the output to a file.**
>
> Note: the save() method is actually syntactic sugar for calling both
>   output() and run().
>
> <...>
>
> **The end event is emitted when processing has finished**. Listeners receive ffmpeg standard output and standard error as arguments, except when generating thumbnails (see below), in which case they receive an array of the generated filenames.

The stream can be promisified as any other stream:

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ffmpeg(filename)
    .toFormat('mp3')
    .on('error', reject)
    .on('progress', (progress) => {
        console.log('Processing: ' + progress.targetSize + ' KB converted');
    })
    .on('end', resolve)
    .save(`./${newname}.mp3`)
});
```

Comment: so `.on("end ")` will call after save ?

Comment: The question is not entirely correct. `save` is synchronous call; it's an instruction on what the stream should do. It's `end` *callback* that is called after `save`. I suppose that's what you meant, and the answer is yes.